# Got Segmention fault in my function after do malloc for char *

Tags: c

Like i said in title, i have that problem. This is my code, i try with `printf` function to check where stops program and find that `for` loop causes that issue? Thank on any advice! I want with this function to return address to char pointer.

```
char *my_getline(int len)
{
  char *p = (char *) malloc(len); // I tried also without (char *), it's same thing.
  if ( p == NULL)
  return NULL;

  int d,c;
  for ( d = 0;d<len-1 && (c=getchar())!= EOF && c!= '\n';d++)
     *p++ = c;


  if ( c == '\n')
     {
        *p = '\0';
        return p;
     }
    else
        return NULL;


 }
```

EDIT: Submitted length is defined to 100, and that isn't so much substantially, because when i enter one char, program crushes.

Comment: Returning p isn't terribly useful since it points at the NULL character at the end of the string.  You need to preserve the original pointer to the beginning of the block so you can free it later and so you can actually use the string.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: That is an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Svante It's an issue with the code, but it won't fix the crash, so to me it's a comment.

Comment: @Svante: It's almost an answer -- it'd explain why the string being returned is always empty, and why `free` might cause a segfault.  I don't know if it'd explain all the oddity, though.  (And it certainly isn't the only problem with this code.)

Comment: Tnx @RetiredNinja for that, i forgotten that element.

Comment: Also, if c is EOF, you just return NULL, and leak p.

Comment: @rpattiso In effect, i think on free function but, that issue take to me ocupation for her.

Comment: There's also a leak if the input doesn't end with a newline before the length is reached.  There are many issues.  It would be nice to see a complete example to know what length is being passed in and such.

Comment: As another observation, the use of the 'for' construct there is a little...odd. Reworking as a while would more closely mimic the process being implemented, it'd seem.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Submitted length is defined to 100.

Comment: Why did I receive down-vote?

Answer (score 4):

There is a function `fgets` in C that already provides what you seek to achieve. Your code could be replaced by:

```
char *p = (char *) malloc(len);
fgets(p, len, stdin);`
```

Comment: well yes but there's a big chance that you end up in the mess that you're in right now

Comment: So let's fix that, for fun.

Comment: have fun in the other answer(s) while I'm spending my time on problems that haven't been solved yet

Comment: So u think it solved, if i get alternate way to save input? , maybe in your opinion, but i want to implement like this.

Comment: @Tartar_sos: Feel free to implement it however you like...but know that you're taking something that's already been done and complicating it all to hell.  You could instead be spending that time/effort doing whatever you wanted a line of text for.  :)

Answer (score 0):

As **Lee Daniel Crocker** commented, you are incrementing the pointer and then returning the incremented value, you have two options, you can return `p - d`

```
char *my_getline(int len)
{
    char *p = malloc(len);
    int   d, c;
    if (p == NULL)
        return NULL;
    for (d = 0 ; d < len - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c!= '\n'; d++)
        *p++ = c;
    *p = '\0';

    return p - d;
}
```

which youd point back to the begining of the data, or store the begining in a variable and return that

```
char *my_getline(int len)
{
    char *p = malloc(len);
    char *ptr;
    int   d, c;
    if (p == NULL)
        return NULL;
    ptr = p;
    for (d = 0 ; d < len - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c!= '\n'; d++)
        *p++ = c;
    *p = '\0';

    return ptr;
}
```

Comment: `d < len - 1` is the condition

Comment: I set in for loop to increment d to ( len - 1).

Comment: The problem is that he's incrementing p and returning that modified value.

Comment: I think the problem is in first loop for. I tried to printf some text after for but it doesnt appear. And of course and that is problem  @LeeDanielCrocker

Comment: What are you passing to printf after the for loop? p? p has already been changed by then, so it won't tell you much.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker i print somelike "tree"

Comment: @Tartar_sos, must be something else, no crash nor a single memory error tested passing arbitrary input and a memory debugger `valgrind`.

Comment: U fix return address, how i can see, but that is secondary problem.

Comment: @Tartar_sos _`U fix return address, how i can see, but that is secondary problem.`_

Comment: And? if u don't know what it's meaning u have google translate. I don't want up your answer because my program still crush. Tnx for your advice.

Comment: @Tartar_sos your program is crashing for something else, why don't you post the `main()` function?

Comment: Why u need main function, when i define length at 100 like i said, and it is transmitted to *my_getline function.